# How to make custom filter for IE 6/7/8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, filter, cross-browser

**How to make custom filter for IE 6/7/8 (Cross Browser Issue)**

```
-ms-accelerator
::-ms-backdrop
-ms-behavior
-ms-filter
-ms-fullscreen
-ms-interpolation-mode
filter
```

HTML

```
<ELEMENT STYLE=
"filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(sProperties)" ... >
```

Internet Explorer 5.5 or later

Scripting

```
object .style.filter =
"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(sProperties)"
```

Comment: what exactly is the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**USE this link for Filter information :**

Multimedia Filters, supported in IE5.5+, allows you to easily add rich visual effects to your content. Defined using CSS and further manipulated using JavaScript, below is our comprehensive IE Filters and Transitions reference.

[**http://www.javascriptkit.com/filters/filters.shtml**](http://www.javascriptkit.com/filters/filters.shtml)

Comment: this is only filter list, How to make custom filter for IE 6/7/8?